# How to make the credentials not be expired after assume a role in another account in ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I am creating a application with KCL to get records from kinesis which is in another account A.

I assume a role which is in account A to get a temp credentials to get records from kinesis. but it will be expired in a short time. After the credentials are expired, the KCL will not be stopped, just sleep a while and wakeup again.

How can I avoid the credentials expired.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "get a temp credentials"? Is KCL running in Account B, but pulling Kinesis records from Account A? Are you using roles assigned to the EC2 instance, which would handle credentials automatically?

Comment: As John suggested, use the role on the EC2 instances that you are using for your KCL. When you do that, EC2 is managing the refresh of the temporary credentials.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But we can't create a instance profile attached the role from other account,right?

Comment: You can give cross account permission to a specific role (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

Comment: I know this. But the credentials is temp, it will be expired after about 1 hours. right?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) is that it gives you *temporary* credentials.

If you want to give something permanent credentials, just create some creds on an IAM user and give those to your program. Those are permanent.